# Unable to call the OZ PaymentSplitter release method from my tests

Tags: nft, hardhat, openzeppelin, chai, virtual

I'm using hardhat, chai to write my tests for an nft sample project im working on.

Have set up the PaymentSplitter like so ...

```
contract MyNft is ERC721A, Ownable, MerkleWhitelist, PaymentSplitter {
    .....


    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI,
        string memory _initNotRevealedUri,
        address[] memory _payees,
        uint256[] memory _shares
    ) ERC721A(_name, _symbol) PaymentSplitter(_payees, _shares) payable {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
    }
}
```

And when testing the Payment splitter with my nft, all tests pass except for the release test (the last test) with the error

`TypeError: mynft.release is not a function`

```
describe("PaymentSplitter", () => {
   // deploy myn
   beforeEach(async () => {
     await mynft.setPause(false)
     await mynft.setWhitelistMintingPeriod(false)

     await mynft.connect(user1).mint(8, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.16") })
     await mynft.connect(user2).mint(2, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.04") })
   })

    it("Should have totalShares to equal 100", async () => {
      const totalShares = await mynft.totalShares()
      console.log('totalShares', totalShares)
      expect(totalShares.toNumber()).to.equal(100)
    })

    it("Should have the correct share split", async () => {
      const user1Shares = await mynft.shares(user1.address)
      const user2Shares = await mynft.shares(user2.address)

      expect(user1Shares.toNumber()).to.equal(60)
      expect(user2Shares.toNumber()).to.equal(40)
    })

    it("Should release the correct amount for the user", async () => {
      const a = await mynft.release(user1.address) // error occurs here
      console.log('a', a)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

ethers handles overloaded functions differently - https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/migration/web3/-%23-migration-from-web3-js--contracts--overloaded-functions

changing

`const a = await mynft.release(user1.address)`

to

`const a = await mynft['release(address)'].(user1.address)`

should do the trick.